# Remotely access MongoDB as Docker container running on Ubuntu Server 16.04 via SSH

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

I successfully deployed MongoDB instance (image [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb/)) on my Docker running on my remote Ubuntu 16.04 server.

When I try to remotely open a connection to MongoDB instance from my computer using Robo 3T I get this message :

[image]

Here is my connection configuration :

[image]

[image]

For information, here is the output of `docker ps` :

[image]

Comment: Why you are using "localhost" when you are trying "remote connection"?

Comment: @kosa because once I'm conencted with ssh via port 22 it's on localhost of my remote server. I've even tried with the server IP but didn't worked

Comment: Are you sure mongo is listening to 27027 port? default is 27017, try with it.

Comment: @matthPen see my last screenshot please .. I think there is a custom config need to be done to permit external access !

Comment: i saw it! unless you configure mongo to listen to 27027 port,  mongo will not be reachable on this port. configure it (/etc/mongod.conf) or cahnge your binding port to -p 27027:27017 (so port 27027 on host is redirected to 27017 on container). But ssh+port binding on host acts for mongodb in container as localhost  => no restriction from here

Comment: @matthPen exactly ! I already expose the port using -p 27027:27027 .. I don't understand what's going wrong

Comment: you expose port 27027, but there's nothing at this port in container! 27017 is the default one!

Comment: I think yes ! Is there a way to check ? Normally by defaut MongoDB listens on 27027

Comment: no, 27017. check the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/)

Comment: in the [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb/~/dockerfile/) of the image they set 27027 as `MONGODB_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER`

Comment: really?? i read 27017!

Comment: I'm sorry It's my bad ! now I can't connect to mongodb but still one small problem : I need to use internal ip adress `172.17.0.2` otherwise (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) It won't be able to connect

Comment: with expose 27017 it's normal. Bind 27017:27017 when you run container to access with localhost

Comment: You're awesome man xoxo thank you everything works fine now